# Unable to upload screenshots to G Suite Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, gsuite-addons

I tried to upload a screenshot to publish a private Spreadsheet add-on.
However, it did not complete with a "Not saved" message.

["Not saved" message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2EEp.png)

The screenshot field is a required and I cannot publish the add-on.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click "Add screenshot"
2. Upload an image
3. Click “Done"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The [requirements](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/sdk#graphic_assets) for a screenshot are:

> Screenshots of your application. At least one is required, but you can
> optionally provide up to five screenshots. These should be 1280 x 800
> pixels in size. If necessary, screenshots 640 x 400 pixels or 2560 x
> 1600 pixels in size can be used. Your screenshots should have square
> corners and no padding (full bleed).

[image]

- After uploading a screenshot that fulfills the requirements you need to make sure that all other required fields (e.g. Developer website
  ) are filled out
- Once all required fields are filled out correctly, the `Update` button becomes enabled

[image]

- After clicking on the `Update` button your screenshot and other changes will become saved

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  
I checked again carefully and noticed that "Post Install Tip" was not entered.  
After entering "Post Install Tip", `Publish` button was enabled.  
I'm ashamed of my carelessness...

Comment: I understand. Thank you for all your advice!